# Can you modify a sharepoint 2010 approval form created from the browser "add a workflow" from list settings?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The client prefers to be able to create their own workflows so this method works well, however I would like to modify it so that I can add code to toggle some fields.

Also how do I modify the email sent out form the approval forms?
I can't seem to find anywhere to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the site in SPD and open the List/Library. Now in the overview page you can see the workflows associated with the List/Library.

Double clicking this will take you to the workflow page where you can edit the task behavior.

Comment: Amal , thank you I understand that however the workflows I speak of are the browser created ones. So if I double click in it and it does is open the browser workflow with it's limited choices. What I seek is how to get in that code to add toggles for this particular workflow.

Comment: Someone please answer the question in regards to the "browser" being mentioned? My question was "Can you modify a sharepoint 2010 approval form created from the BROWSER “add a workflow” from list settings? " NOT how to modify an approval form period but an OOTB Approval form.